# Send files to S3 using Tumbleweed Secure File Transport

Tags: amazon-s3, tumbleweed

My org uses Tumbleweed Secure File Transport to transfer files to different locations. 
I have a requirement to move files to S3 but am not sure whether this is possible using Tumbleweed.
The way my org currently does it is to sftp the files across to an EC2 instance which then transfers it to S3.
Does anyone know if Tumbleweed can send files directly to S3?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

S3 uploading is secure, and there are numerous tools that implement the API. The AWS CLI, SDKs, and 3rd party applications. Even if Tumbleweed doesn't support it, you can find a tool that does

Comment: I have used the other ways and know about them. However, my org uses Tumbleweed and wanted to see if was capable of this.